Find the 5% upper quantile of the ratio of two chi-square independent random variables
Let $X$ ~ $\chi^2_7$ and $Z$ following the standard normal distribution, being two independent random variables.
I'm trying to calculate the 5% upper quantile of $Z^2/X$  and $Z/\sqrt X$ without using the concept of $\beta'  distribution$.
For $Z^2/X$, My thought is to write $Z^2/X$ into $(Z^2/1)/(X/7) $, which follows a F distrbution with degree of freedom 1,7. However, there will be a constant $1/7$ multiplying $(Z^2/1)/(X/7) $, so I'm not sure am my idea correct.

$\mathrm{(i)}$
Define $Y:=\frac{Z^2}{X}$ and let $f_\alpha$ be the $\alpha$-level right quantile of the F distribution $\mathrm{F}(1,7)$. We have
\begin{align}\alpha &= \mathbb P[\mathrm{F}(1,7)>f_\alpha]= \mathbb P\Bigl[\frac{Z^2/1}{X/7}>f_\alpha\Bigr]\\&=\mathbb P[7Y>f_\alpha]=\mathbb P\bigl[Y>\frac{1}{7}f_\alpha\bigr].\end{align}
Hence we get that the $\alpha$-level right quantile of $Y$ is $$y_\alpha=\frac{1}{7}f_\alpha$$
$\mathrm{(ii)}$ Define $Y:=\frac{Z}{\sqrt X}$ and let $t_\alpha$ be the $\alpha$-level right quantile of the t distribution $\mathrm{t}(7)$. We have
\begin{align}\alpha &= \mathbb P[\mathrm{t}(7)>t_\alpha]= \mathbb P\Bigl[\frac{Z}{\sqrt{X}/\sqrt7}>t_\alpha\Bigr]\\&=\mathbb P[\sqrt{7}\,Y>t_\alpha]=\mathbb P\bigl[Y>\frac{1}{\sqrt7}t_\alpha\bigr].\end{align}
Hence we get that the $\alpha$-level right quantile of $Y$ is $$y_\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt7}t_\alpha$$
